# How can I access the properties of a JavaScript class from inside a promise? (Using ES6 not Self)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, ecmascript-6

I am using ES6 classes to create an angular controller.  I am trying to use promises to load my products.  When I call getProducts the results comes back with the data I need, however the **this** in this.products = results is undefined and I get "Cannot set property 'products' of undefined".  How can I access the properties from inside of then?

```
export class ProductController {  
  constructor (Product) {
    'ngInject';

    this.ProductService = Product;
    this.products = [];    
    this.getProducts();
  }

    getProducts() {
      this.ProductService
        .find()
        .$promise
        .then(function (results) {
            this.products = results;
        }, function (results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: one way is to use arrow `=>` functions ... so `.then(results => this.products = results, results => console.log(results));`

Comment: I tried to replace 

function (results) {
this.products = results;
}

with

(results) => this.products = results

with no luck

Comment: Arrow functions are the way to go here. But notice that you actually shouldn't write asynchronously received data to instance properties - just store the promise itself in the property and many things will be easier.

Comment: your issue is elsewhere then - do you get any errors ion your console?

Comment: @Bergi - that sort of pattern seems common in angularjs

Comment: @JaromandaX using the arrow functions did in fact fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

> Disclaimer: I'm not incredibly familiar with ES6, so this may be an outdated approach.

My general approach to avoiding issues with `this` is to rename it:

```
getProducts() {
  let self = this
  this.ProductService
    .find()
    .$promise
    .then(function (results) {
        self.products = results;
    }, function (results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
}
```